# How can I put use else if and then put the value into the table in trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have two tables: `project` and `postponedproject`
I created three triggers happening after updating the `duedate` in `project` : `change_project_duedate` and `postponedproject_status` and `postponedproject_difference`

The first one is to take the old and updated `duedate` and project table primary key `prono` to the `postponedproject` table :

```
create or replace trigger change_project_duedate
after update of duedate on project
for each row
begin
insert into postponedproject (Prono, oldduedate, newduedate, status, difference, reason)
values (:old.prono, :old.duedate, :new.duedate, null, null, null);
end;
```

The second one is to see if the `newduedate` is later than old `oldduedate` or not and then put the value into the `postponedproject.status`:

```
create or replace trigger postponedproject_status
before insert on postponedproject
for each row
declare
differencestatement postponedproject.status%type;
begin
if :new.newduedate > :new.oldduedate then
    differencestatement := 'Project has been delayed';
Else 
    differencestatement := 'Project has been scheduled to finish eariler';
end if;
    insert into postponedproject (status)
    values (differencestatement);
end;
```

The third one is to see put the value `difference` between `oldduedate` and `newduedate` in the table of `postponedproject`:

```
create or replace trigger postponedproject_difference
before insert on postponedproject
for each row
begin
:new.difference := :new.newduedate - :new.oldduedate;
end;
```

However, it gave me an error like this when I update the `duedate` in the project table:

```
Error report -
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "21363937.POSTPONEDPROJECT_STATUS", line 9
ORA-04
```

I really appreciate if anyone can give me a hand. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger `postponedproject_status` on table `postponedproject` executes an insert on table `postponedproject`. Which will cause the trigger to fire. Which will insert a record into `postponedproject`. Which will cause the trigger to fire. Which will ... and so on until you reach fifty levels of recursion.

Instead of executing an INSERT you just need to do an assignment to the :NEW namespace.

Also, you don't need two triggers. Discard `postponedproject_difference` and put the assignment in the other trigger:

```
create or replace trigger postponedproject_status
before insert on postponedproject
for each row
declare
    differencestatement postponedproject.status%type;
begin

    :new.difference := :new.newduedate - :new.oldduedate;

    if :new.newduedate > :new.oldduedate then
        differencestatement := 'Project has been delayed';
    Else 
        differencestatement := 'Project has been scheduled to finish eariler';
    end if;

    :new.status := differencestatement;

end;
```

Probably you should give it a more generic name.

Comment: it works perfectly fine, thank you so much for your help!